# How to label x-axis with non-time series data in Grafana with Elasticsearch data source?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-plugin, grafana-templating, grafana-api

I have a dashboard in Grafana that displays the percentage of utilization of multiple servers. The x-axis is labeled with time-series(timestamp), I want to label it as server names.

[This is how x-axis looks like with time series.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DJTa.png)

[This is what I want the graph to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE3Q9.png)

Note: The data source is strictly Elasticsearch and cannot be converted to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to flip your axes - X to Series instead of Time - that would allow you group by series. Something like below (sourced from https://play.grafana.org/d/000000014/elasticsearch-metrics?editPanel=1)

[image]